# change the full image based on thumb which is clicked does not work, method is in service

Tags: angular, angular7

i have created a gallery app in Angular, which displays 3 thumbs and one big image. Based on clicked thumb the full image should - **but does not**- change - data and methods are in service one level up. 
When i console.log *fullImage* on images.component.ts <- value does not change
Can someone please point out the mistake for me 
(git repo with code: https://github.com/GosiaPtak/gallery-app)
gallery.service.ts

```
import images from '../../assets/images.json';


export class GalleryService {
  thumbsDomain: string = images.properties.photos.items.properties.image.chance.url.domain.replace('/300/150', '/200/133');
  thumbsUrls: string[] = [];
  imagesDomain: string = images.properties.photos.items.properties.image.chance.url.domain.replace('/300/150', '/600/400');
  imagesNumber: string[] = ['?image=1001', '?image=1002', '?image=1003'];
  displayedImage: string = this.imagesDomain + this.imagesNumber[0];

getUrls = () => {
  this.imagesNumber.forEach((value) =>  this.thumbsUrls.push(this.thumbsDomain + value));
  //
}
onDislayImage = (i: number) => { // (click)="onSetDislayedImage(i)" <- in thumbnails.component.html
  this.displayedImage = this.imagesDomain + this.imagesNumber[i];
  console.log(this.displayedImage);
}
}
```

images.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { GalleryService } from '../gallery.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-images',
  templateUrl: './images.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./images.component.scss']
})
export class ImagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
fullImage: string;
  constructor(private imagesService: GalleryService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fullImage = this.imagesService.displayedImage;
  }
ngOnDestroy(): void {}
}
```

structure of app:

1 lvl - App 
2 lvl -- Gallery 
2 lvl -- gallery.service.ts

3 lvl --- thumbnails.component.ts 
3 lvl --- (click)="onSetDislayedImage(i)" <- in thumbnails.component.html 
3 lvl --- images.component.ts 
3 lvl ---  <- in images.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need e.g. a ReplaySubject in your gallery service:

```
subject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

onDislayImage = (i: number) => {
this.displayedImage = this.imagesDomain + this.imagesNumber[i];
this.subject.next(this.displayedImage);
}

yourSubject(): ReplaySubject<any> {
return this.subject;
}
```

Inside your images component ngOnit you can add something like:

```
this.fullImage = this.imagesService.displayedImage;
this.imagesService.yourSubject().asObservable().subscribe((res) => {
this.fullImage = res;
});
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe on destroy.

Comment: Thank you. After some reading and learning i decided to start with: ``` activeImage = new Subject();  this.activeImage.next(this.displayedImage = this.imagesDomain + this.imagesNumber[i]);```